# Why isn't my rig moving with my mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature

First making rig, the mesh isn't moving with it. Why isn't this working?

[image: screenshot of the model and rig]

Here is my file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6gkq804ull5w0fpp702kx/untitled.blend?rlkey=xgpxh5nrbsmb8zj9dhkubn2yo&dl=0

Comment: Hello, please provide some screenshots of your rig and upload your file directly instead of through an external link. :)

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is a bit complicated: You have separate objects and separate armatures, your objects are only parented to the *Spine* armature, and they are not subdivided, so they won't be able to bend. Unless you have good reason to keep it this way, maybe simplify your setup: Join all the armatures together, make sure that the bones are correctly named (with the .R or _R suffixe), join all the objects together, create some edge loops if you want them to bend a bit. Parent the object to the armature *With Empty Groups*. In *Edit* mode, select the vertices and assign to the vertex group you want them to be assigned to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to blender. I think this would be very helpful if you put it simpler terms. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).  You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/315250/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: @MillaBell What do you need in simpler terms? If subdividing, joining, edge loops are too complicated terms, I would really highly recommend watching beginner tutorials to learn basic modeling and some tools in Blender.

Comment: sorry, I was tired and so read it a bit more carefully. This answers my question